# How to format a const string

Tags: rust

How can I make part of a `const` string conditional on some flag?

```
#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
const OS: &'static str = "OSx";
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
const OS: &'static str = "Windows";

const SOME_STRING: &'static str = format!("this os is {}", OS);
```

This code doesn't compile because the `format` macro returns a `String`. I'd like to be able to do this formatting without any allocation. Is it possible to do without making the whole string conditional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for one, you should be aware of http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/consts/constant.OS.html

Second, you can't *really* do this, exactly. You could use the `lazy_static` crate, but that's still going to end up giving you an allocation.

In the future, when `const fn` is stable, this should  be easier to do.

Comment: Is `const fn` also going to allow things like `const sqrt_of_two: f64 = (2.0).sqrt()` to be possible?

Comment: You *can* do it by abusing the heck out of macros... but it's unlikely to be worth it.  *Really* unlikely.

Comment: @Jsor: Maybe. It is unclear how much Compile Time Function Evaluation (CTFE) Rust will end up having. Personally, I am on the "everything that is self-contained" side, but I am not calling the shots :)

Comment: "In the future, when const fn is stable, this should be easier to do.", are we in the future yet?

Comment: while const fn is stable, the bits of it that you would need here (allocation) are not.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [const_format](https://docs.rs/const_format/latest/const_format/) crate to do this.

```rs
use const_format::formatcp;

#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
const OS: &'static str = "OSx";
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
const OS: &'static str = "Windows";

const SOME_STRING: &'static str = formatcp!("this os is {}", OS);

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", SOME_STRING);
}
```

```
this os is Windows
```

(This code is just for example as you could simply copy `"this os is"` into each of the cfg strings, and also should consider using [`std::env::const::OS`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/consts/constant.OS.html))