# Interpolate string in const function

Tags: rust, string-interpolation, compile-time-constant

Im trying to make a function similar to this

```
pub const fn insert(num1:i32, num2:i32) -> &'static str { 
    formatcp!("n1:{}, n2:{}" , num1, num2) 
}
```

But num1/num2 are not const.
I think this would be possible as a macro but im not experienced in macros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a const string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279858/how-to-format-a-const-string)

Comment: Chayim Friedman Not really, since the answer is from a 2015 where const fn where in nightly and not finished. By now you can create constants as a result of a const fn. My question focuses on string interpolation with arguments in a compile time context.

Comment: The crates it refers to, `const_format`, still works (I don't know about inside `const fn`, but it should work).

Comment: The macro is complaining that the parameters(num1, num2) are not const. I also tried Generic constants (<const num1:i32, const num2:i32>) not working.

Comment: Ah ok. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Can you use nightly?

Comment: I can but naturally a stable solution would be better ; )

Comment: Is that _must_ be the signature of the function, or it can be a little different (for example, return an array that will be converted to `&str` at call site)?

Comment: That would be possible

Comment: Where will the result get used? If you can adjust the signature, maybe you can just use `const_format`? It is not much different, and uses the same ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244765/discussion-between-redcrafter-lp-and-chayim-friedman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it help?

```rust
macro_rules! insert {
    ($n1:expr, $n2:expr) => {
        concat!("n1: ", $n1, " , n2: ", $n2)
    };
}

const TEST_1: &str = insert!(1, 2);
const TEST_2: &str = insert!(2, 3);

fn main() {
    println!("{}", TEST_1);
    println!("{}", TEST_2);
}
```

Comment: That's a great solution. Didn't know that you could use concat! in a const context. The only thing missing is, that the macro parameters are not i32. But that's easily fixable by adding 2 constants of i32 in the macro and assign the parameters to it.